# How to filter IRI correctly in Blazegraph RDF?

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, triplestore, blazegraph

How can I make a proper SPARQL query to filter out entities using their IRI? Currently, I am getting empty set when I try to filter by IRI.

I am using Blazegraph DB and I run this SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?y ?p ?g
WHERE
> { ?y ?p ?g .
FILTER regex(?g, "Svet", "i") }
```

The result is the following:
[Result filter by Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUIbE.png)

But when I run the query on the same data by subject:

```
SELECT ?y ?p ?g
WHERE
{ ?y ?p ?g .
  FILTER regex(?y, "www", "i") }
```

I get an empty result:
[Result filter by Subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq60U.png)

Comment: `?y` is either an IRI or a bnode. `regex` works on strings, thus, do `regex(str(?y), "www", "i")`

Comment: There is also `hint:Query hint:regexMatchNonString true .` in Blazegraph.

Comment: UninformedUser and Stanislav, both approaches worked for me. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/):

> *17.4.3.14 REGEX*
>
> ```
> xsd:boolean REGEX(string literal text, simple literal pattern)
> xsd:boolean REGEX(string literal text, simple literal pattern, simple literal flags)
> ```

> *17.4.2.5 str*
>
> ```
> simple literal STR(literal ltrl)
> simple literal STR(IRI rsrc)
> ```
>
> Returns the lexical form of `ltrl` (a literal); returns the codepoint representation of `rsrc` (an IRI). This is useful for examining parts of an IRI, for instance, the host-name.

In Blazegraph, there is a [query hint](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/QueryHints) which is equivalent of always using `str()`:

```
hint:Query hint:regexMatchNonString true .
```

There is also a system property which is equivalent of always using this query hint:

```
-Dcom.bigdata.rdf.sparql.ast.QueryHints.regexMatchNonString=true
```